# Formatting Text Awk Sed

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed

Hi I have a file that I need to put in a format that I can pull into excel spreadsheet  I do not know how to do this and I would appreciate if you could help me out.

Here is the input sample

```
#1

Indiana University—​Bloomington (Kelley) 
Bloomington, IN

90  58  82  86 
#1

Temple University (Fox) 
Philadelphia, PA

95  66  97  95 
#1

University of North Carolina—​Chapel Hill (Kenan-​Flagler) 
Chapel Hill, NC

73  58  100     75 
#4
```

Here is the output

```
#1, Indiana University—​Bloomington (Kelley) Bloomington, IN,   90, 58, 82, 86,
#1, Temple University (Fox) Philadelphia, PA,           95,     66,     97,     95,
```

I'm using shell scripting in linux

Thanks

Comment: by the way, it's a very bad idea to use `,` as delimiter -- `Philadelphia, PA` contains a `,`, so wherever you use that file, you'll have unforeseen consequences.

Comment: Thanks this is working. Grateful for quick community response.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is rather simple with GNU awk and mawk if you don't try to use it in a line-based manner. We'll use a `#` at the beginning of a line as record separator and a newline as a field separator. Then:

```
awk -v RS='(^|\n)#' -F'\n' 'NR > 1 { gsub(/ +/, ", ", $6); print "#" $1 ", " $3 " " $4 ", " $6 }' filename
```

That is:

```
NR > 1 {                              # the first record is the empty bit before
                                      # the first separator, so we skip it
  gsub(/ +/, ", ", $6)                # then: insert commas in the number row
  print "#" $1 ", " $3 " " $4 ", " $6 # and reassemble the record in the right
                                      # format for printing.
}
```

The use of a regex as record separator is not strictly POSIX-conforming, but between gawk and mawk, you'll have most bases covered.

Comment: Nice :) Thanks for giving an `awk` answer (ok, `gawk`, but who in BSD hell uses anything else?). Also, you give a nice example of why usage of `awk` might not be the easiest approach at all times, but often there *is* an elegant solution like yours. Kudos!

Comment: @MarcusMüller I've seen boxes that only had mawk, and there are some features of gawk that mawk doesn't understand (notably `ENDFILE`, which caused me some grief). Happily, mawk understands regex `RS` as well, and other awks are rare these days.

Comment: :) it's just that I've given up on anything but `grep -e` and `sed` by now for exactly this reason -- you try to be as universal as possible (ie. respecting systems where scripting language interpreters are not available), but you end up fixing your scripts to actually work with the strange things you encounter out there. And then, someone throws Windows paths at your script, and everything bursts into flames. Ah -- nearly forgot to upvote your answer :)

Comment: @MarcusMüller Is this a bad time to mention BSD sed? :P Portable sed is very nearly impossible to achieve for anything beyond the most simple of scripts. If you want a cabinet of sed breaking in horrible ways, search the questions that are tagged both macosx and sed sometime (Mac OS X comes with BSD sed).

Comment: /me decides to die on the spot.

Comment: Thanks the awk command work. Very grateful for quick response

Answer (score 1):

Awk script to solve the problem:

```
/^#[0-9]/ {current = $0}

/\([A-Za-z ]+\)/ { current = current "," $0}

/[A-Z]+$/ { current = current $0}

/^[0-9]+/ {current = current "," $1 "," $2 "," $3 "," $4; print current}
```

Usage:

```
cat yourdatafile | awk -f script.awk > output.csv
```

Explanation:

Each of the regexes match the patterns on the different lines and executes the action for that line beside the regex.

- For the #number, initialize/overwrite a current variable with the #number.
- For the text info without a state, add it to the current variable with a comma at the start
- For the text info with a State, add it to the current variable without a comma at the start
- For the list of numbers, add them to the current variable with a comma at the start and in between each then print the current variable

Answer (score 0):

While it's entirely possible you can do that with a bit of `awk` scripting, I'd recommend you don't do that.

Actually, `awk` is handy for anything that's not too complex, but here, since you're already planning to use Excel, you might as well just import the plain file, and then process it in excel, pivoting, reshaping, splitting it there.

However, I *hate* Excels complexity, so here's my python2 approach (saving it as `program.py` and making it executable as `chmod 755 program.py`):

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys

wholefile = open(sys.argv[1], "r").read()
parts = wholefile.split("#")

for item in parts:
    lines = item.split("\n")
    output = [ int(lines[0]), lines[2], lines[3],lines[5].split() ]
    print ";".join(output)
```

and run this as

```
program.py input.txt > output.csv
```

EDIT: typo, and:

I tend to say this too often, but doing something in a shell script that isn't very centered on the wish to invoke a lot of commands is often far less effective than using any general purpose scripting language. Python is so abundant everywhere that I seldom find myself writing bash scripts.

EDIT2: Ok, so no python on your host. scary ;P. Use `bash`'s built-in `read` function (`man read`).

Comment: Thx but I cannot use python its not supported on the host

Comment: Ok, that sparks my interest: which self-respecting host gives you access to a bash shell, and all the standard GNU tools, but not to python? Is there perl, php (ugh), *anything* available?

Comment: Added the hint to use `read` from the `bash` built-in functions; it supports variable and array assignment and might fit your need quite nicely if used in a loop

Comment: Hi yes. Perl is available. The sa i s telling me that phyton is not part of the standard built as a result it cannot be installed and supported. Sorry I do appreciate ur responses

Comment: oh well. I don't like Perl, so I don't have a version of that script for you :) Use @Wintermute 's solution!

Comment: Thx Marcus for trying I appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

```
 sed '#n;/[0-9 ]/ s/  */, /g;/^ *$/d;H;$!b;g;s/.//;s/\n\([^#]\)/, \1/g;p' YourFile
```

- remove and preformat entry line
- hold the remaining info
- at the end, load the buffer
- remove first newline
- replace any new line not followed by a `#` by a `,` and the followed char itself
- print the result

if the last `,` is mandatory (normaly not in a csv/excel file) adapt the `/[0-9 ]/ s/  */, /g` with this `;/[0-9 ]/ {s/  */, /g; s/$/,/;}`

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative way of doing it with awk by only manipulating the output field separator (`OFS`) and the output record separator (`ORS`):

```
grep -v '^$' infile |      # remove empty lines
awk 'NR%4 { ORS=", "; OFS=" " } NR%4 == 0 { ORS="\n"; OFS=", " } $1=$1'
```

Output:

```
#1, Indiana University—​Bloomington (Kelley), Bloomington, IN, 90, 58, 82, 86
#1, Temple University (Fox), Philadelphia, PA, 95, 66, 97, 95
#1, University of North Carolina—​Chapel Hill (Kenan-​Flagler), Chapel Hill, NC, 73, 58, 100, 75
#4,
```